# How to make a New Window function to open in the parent page of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to get this function to open the window in the page which is holding the iframe aka the parent page.

Here is the function:

```
function <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_get_office_locator() {
    url = '<?php echo Mage::helper('extensa_econt')->getOfficeLocatorUrl(); ?>' + '&shop_url=<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>';

    if ($F('<?php echo $_htmlId; ?>:office_city_id')) {
        url += '&address=' + $('<?php echo $_htmlId; ?>:office_city_id').options[$('<?php echo $_htmlId; ?>:office_city_id').selectedIndex].text;
    }

    <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_win = new Window({url: url, width: 1000, height: 800, destroyOnClose: true, minimizable: false, maximizable: false, recenterAuto: false, zIndex:9999});
    <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_win.showCenter(false, 50);
}
```

This function is opening the new window inside the iframe, but i want to open it outside the iframe in the page which is calling/holding the iframe aka the parent page.

How can i make this via jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Window is a class of the prototype lib. look there for options. http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/

Comment: So can i make something about it? How can i achieve what i want ?